# JackBox- Responsive Lightbox - Image Viewer, use Javascript function instead of href

Tags: javascript, parameters, href

This is a long shot.... but I hope someone can help.

I'm using a JackBox - Responsive Lightbox - and it works fine with a static HTML, but I want to change the code to be more flexable.

I use DataTables and use a model to view more details - including photos of the main asset and an image if the area/asset is "excluded" - so there could be 100's of items in the list.

If I use the static link:

```
<a class="jackbox data-group="text_link"  data-title="Text Link"
href="/system/showImage.php? 
subFolder=assetPhotos/Legionella/Assets&filename=main121212.jpg">View</a>
```

Everything works fine...

However, if the global variable **exclusion** is set to "**main121212.jpg**" and I change the above to:

```
<a class="jackbox"  data-group="text_link"  data-title="Text Link" 
href="javascript:showImageForJackBox('assetPhotos/Asbestos/Assets', 
'exclusion')">View</a>
```

and have the function **showImageForJackBox** declared as to:

```
  showImageForJackBox = function(path,outImageFile) {
     switch (outImageFile.toString()) {
        case "exclusion":
           theFile = exclusion ;
           break;
        default:
           theFile = "" ;
     }

     location.href = "'/system/showImage.php?subFolder=" + path + "&filename=" + theFile ;           
  }
```

I get an error in the debugger console of firebox saying:

referenceError: showImageForJackBox is not defined

javascript:showImageForJackBox('assetPhotos/Asbestos/Assets', 'exclusion'):1:1

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can go about ensuring the function is referenced.

Thank you in advance for any help given

Answer (score 0):

ARGH Idiot!

I just needed to change the "Attributes" - so after the AJAX call to find the filename for the exclusion... I just changed the href and data-thumbnail Attributes!

```
           exclusionPhoto = data.exclusionPhoto ;
           if (exclusionPhoto === null ) { exclusionPhoto = "" ;}

           var a = document.getElementById('viewExclusionPhoto');
           a.setAttribute("href", "/system/showImage.php?subFolder=assetPhotos/Asbestos/Assets&filename=" + exclusionPhoto);
           a.setAttribute("data-thumbnail", "/system/showImage.php?subFolder=assetPhotos/Asbestos/Assets&filename=" + exclusionPhoto);
```